# How to connect USB device to a phone doesn't have OTG

Tags: usb-on-the-go

1. What are hardware and software difference between OTG support and non-OTG support devices (android)?
2. Is there a way to connect non-OTG device with a pendrive (or other) via USB? Is there any hardware limitations if the slave device is powered externally?
3. Does the OTG feature comes with kernal/OS or any android OS (6.0 or later) is capable of OTG if hardware supported? If yes, is it same for Android ONE and AOSP?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_On-The-Go

Comment: @alecxs I went through that article, but here's the problem in practical way. Assume there is a phone that the manufacture says **NO OTG** support. **IF** I connected a pen drive with external power (as the device is unable to supply power), will it work? Is it a hardware limitation or with some software tinkering can it be achieved?

Comment: it does not really matter if it is a hardware limitation unless you have the ability to compile a custom kernel, if it does not support it you won't change this with a app. it is not related to power supply, it has to be announce the host mode (or accept the demand of the OTG adapter by short-circuit pin 4+5 in other words)